# How can I make a random number output prime or not game

Tags: python

I'm trying to make this game where it first asks you the range of your number.

After that it generates a  random number in that range and prints it. Then we have to ans if the printed random number is prime or not. If we choose the right ans, means if we typed prime and the number is prime then it prints 'your answer is right' and if your ans is not right lets say its was not a prime number.

Then it prints 'your answer is incorrect'. I'm a new Python learner.

```
x=float(input('Enter the lowest number: '))
y=float(input('Enter the highest number:'))
import random
num = print(random.randint(0,100))
if num > 1:
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
       else:
         print(num,"is a prime number")
else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

This is my code, so far and it is giving errors already. How can I write the code for this game that I have presented, because it will help me understand and clear my doubts.

Comment: What are the errors you are receiving?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-252dfa5a525f> in <module>()
      3 import random
      4 num = print(random.randint(0,100))
----> 5 if num > 1:
      6    for i in range(2,num):
      7        if (num % i) == 0:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: You are assigning the result of `print(random.randint(0,100))` to `num`. The result of the print function is `None` which is of type `NoneType`.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter  It is giving errors about the 'if function', it says "> is not supported between 'nonetype' and 'int'. I tried many different methods but it still shows error. As a new learner my methods are limited,so it be very helpfull if someone helps.

Comment: @NabilDaoud so what do i do

Comment: I answered below. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Split line 4 into two lines:

```
num = random.randint(0,100)  # First assign the value to num. 
print(num)                   # Then print `num`.
```